Derivation of dual formulation of support vector regression
I'm trying to derive the dual formulation of epsilon-insensitive support vector regression. I think my derivation is correct, but I can't match it up to a result for the dual that I've seen given in  Machine Learning - A First Course for Engineers and Scientists. I'll give my derivation first, then explain my issue in more detail.
The optimisation problem is:
\begin{equation}
    \hat{\theta} = \underset{\boldsymbol{\theta}}{\mathop{\text{arg min}}}{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \max\{0, |y_i -\underbrace{\boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\phi(\mathbf{x}_i)}}_{\hat{y(\mathbf{x}_i)}}| + \epsilon\} + \lambda \Vert \mathbf{\theta} \Vert^2_2}.
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ are the coefficients to learn, $\boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_\star)$ is a transformation of the input $\mathbf{x}_\star$, $\hat{y}(\mathbf{x}_\star) = \boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\phi(\mathbf{x}_\star)}$ is the SVR prediction, $\epsilon$ determines the tube within which we ignore the cost, and  $\lambda$ is the strength of regularisation. In the derivation I will make use of the definition of the Gram matrix:
$$\boldsymbol{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})=\begin{bmatrix}
\kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_1\right) & \kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2\right) & \ldots & \kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_n\right) \\
\kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_2, \mathbf{x}_1\right) & \kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_2, \mathbf{x}_2\right) & \ldots & \kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_2, \mathbf{x}_n\right) \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
\kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{x}_1\right) & \kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{x}_2\right) & \ldots & \kappa\left(\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{x}_n\right)
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the kernel is
$$
\kappa\left(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)=\boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x})^{\top} \boldsymbol{\phi}\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right).$$
This optimisation problem is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
    &\hat{\theta} = \underset{\boldsymbol{\theta}}{\mathop{\text{arg min}}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i+ \lambda \Vert \mathbf{\theta} \Vert^2_2 \\ &\text{s.t. } \xi_i \ge 0, \quad
    \quad\xi_i \ge y_i -\boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\phi(\mathbf{x}_i)} + \epsilon, \quad \xi_i \ge -y_i +\boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\phi(\mathbf{x}_i)} + \epsilon.
    \\ &\text{ for } i=1, \ldots, n.
\end{align*}
The Lagrangian for this problem is
\begin{multline}
     \mathcal{L} = \frac1n \sum^n_{i=1} \xi_i + \lambda \Vert \theta \Vert^2_2  +\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i (-\xi_i - y_i + \boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_i)-\epsilon)\\+\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i (-\xi_i + y_i - \boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_i)-\epsilon)  - \sum^n_{i=1} \delta_i \xi_i.
\end{multline}
where $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \delta_i \ge 0 \, \text{for} \, i=1, \ldots, n$. Using the KKT conditions we have
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \theta_k} &= 2\lambda \theta_k+\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \phi_k(\mathbf{x}_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i \phi_k(\mathbf{x}_i)=0\\\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \xi_k} &= \frac1n -\alpha_k-\beta_k -\delta_k - =0.
\end{align}
From which we find
\begin{align}
\theta_k &= \frac1{2\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^n (\beta_i-\alpha_i)\phi_k(\mathbf{x}_i), \quad k=1, \ldots, n\\ \frac1n &= \alpha_i +\beta_i +\delta_i, \quad i=1, \ldots, n,
\end{align}
and substituting these expressions back into the Lagrangian we find
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} = -\frac1{4\lambda} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n (\beta_i - \alpha_i ) \boldsymbol{\phi}^T(\mathbf{x}_i)\boldsymbol{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_j) (\beta_j-\alpha_j) + \sum^n_{i=1} (\beta_i-\alpha_i)y_i - \sum^n_{i=1}(\beta_i + \alpha_i)\epsilon.
\end{equation}
We can rewrite this in matrix notation and also form the kernel in the first sum to get
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} = -\frac1{4\lambda}(\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\alpha} )^T \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})(\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\alpha} ) + (\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\alpha} )^T \mathbf{y}- \epsilon(\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\alpha} )^T  \mathbf{1}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of ones. So the dual problem is given by
\begin{align*}
    &\underset{\boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\delta}}{\max} \quad\mathcal{L}\\
    &\text{s.t. $\quad \alpha \ge 0$, $\beta \ge 0$, $\delta \ge 0$, $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac1n$}
\end{align*}
Rewriting as a minimisation problem we have
\begin{align*}
    &\underset{\boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\delta}}{\min} \quad  \frac1{4\lambda}(\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\alpha} )^T \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})(\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\alpha} ) - (\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\alpha} )^T \mathbf{y}+ \epsilon(\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\alpha} )^T \mathbf{1}\\
    &\text{s.t. $\quad \alpha \ge 0$, $\beta \ge 0$, $\delta \ge 0$, $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac1n$}
\end{align*}
We can put this into standard quadratic form by rewriting the equation in  block matrix form:
\begin{align}
-\mathcal{L} &= \frac1{4\lambda} \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{H} \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{v} \label{sqf1}\\ 
\mathbf{v} &= \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{\beta} \\\boldsymbol{\alpha}\end{bmatrix}\label{sqf2}\\ 
& \mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X}) & -\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})\\-\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X}) &\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})\end{bmatrix}\label{sqf3}\\ 
\mathbf{c} &= \begin{bmatrix}\epsilon \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{y}\\\epsilon\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{y}\end{bmatrix}\label{sqf4}\\ 
& 0\le \alpha_i, \beta_i \le \frac1n \quad \text{for} \quad i = 1, \ldots, n
\end{align}
where the final condition comes from $\alpha _i+ \beta_i + \gamma_i = \frac1n$. In this form we can solve the problem numerically using standard quadratic optimisation libraries.
I have seen an alternative form for this optimisation problem (e.g. section 8.3 in Machine Learning - A First Course for Engineers and Scientists) where the authors state that this can be expressed as:
\begin{align}
    & \hat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}=\arg \min _{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{\alpha}^{\top} \boldsymbol{K}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X}) \boldsymbol{\alpha}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{\top} \mathbf{y}+\epsilon\|\boldsymbol{\alpha}\|_1 \\
    & \text{subject to} \quad \left|\alpha_i\right| \leq \frac{1}{2 n \lambda} \text {. }
\end{align}
What's the motivation for putting it into this form? How is this derived from the previous set of equations? Is the problem still quadratic like this? If it is how would you put it into standard quadratic form so it can be solved numerically?
